# How to resolve this Safari issue of displaying text fully justified?

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, angular5, mobile-safari

I have a text display issue that is occurring on Safari browsers for MacOS/iOS operating systems.  The text displays incorrectly until the text is selected/deselected.

Text before any interaction with the browser:
[image]

During the selection:
[image]

After the selection has "corrected" the text:
[image]

Other browsers and OSs display correctly when the page loads.

Using BrowserStack, I tested back several versions of Safari.  It was until I tested Safari 6.2 that it displayed correctly.

I am unsure of what the cause is or what the resolution is.

The web page is an Angular 5 SPA.

[Link to Animated GIF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/pragmatic-hook-pockets-the-road-blackmail/safari_macos_mojave.gif)

```css
.newline-to-br {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p _ngcontent-c27="" class="newline-to-br">Kids under 10 free. 
If fishing during hunting season, we would recommend wearing blaze orange for safety purposes. </p>
```

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't a code issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari you cannot have a white space at the very end of a block of text. Space is actually added but the selection can go past the last white space, which is why it wraps and justifies. Clicking on or highlighting the text triggers a redraw which reinterprets the space and aligns it correctly. To fix it, remove the last space before the `</p>`.

```
<p _ngcontent-c27="" class="newline-to-br">Kids under 10 free. 
If fishing during hunting season, we would recommend wearing blaze orange for safety purposes.</p>
```